# Probe specific performance on oscilloscope - offset

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, oscilloscope, probe

I have been having a weird unexplainable issue with my set-up. I am currently testing a flyback converter with a current sense source resistor. The scope shows a DC offset when using two different passive probes

[image]

The measured waveform is the Vd of the switching mosfet, referenced to circuit ground.

White waveform is measured with a P6139B passive probe and
the blue one is measured at the same point with a TPP1000 passive probe. Both probes are connected to a DPO5104B scope. The offset is ~2.5V

More surprisingly, other waveforms do not have this anomaly. I hope that someone would have some answers/explanations

Comment: The TPP1000 is twice the bandwidth and much less capacitance. It might be telling you the truth and the others are lying?

Comment: What DC offset are you talking about? Can you be clear on the waveforms where this DC offset is occurring.

Comment: Cursor placed on the white waveform, the waveform seems to be lifted by 2.5V from ground.

Comment: looks like GAIN of the two probes is different. Have you done probe frequency calibration?

Answer (score 1):

You have inferred an *offset* problem. It is more likely a *gain* problem where the **blue** scope trace has more gain than the **yellow** scope trace.

This is most likely due to probe compensation at higher frequency. Most every X10 attenuator probe has an adjustment screw, so that the probe can adapt to various 'scope input capacitances. Every time you use a probe on a different 'scope channel, you should do an adjustment procedure that will result in a flat frequency response.